# Why is getBitmap method not working?

Tags: android, image, bitmap, uri, media

I'm a noob to android and i want to set an ImageButton image with a file form the SDcard.  However, getBitmap isn't creating a working bitmap.  When i set the ImageButton with the bitmap that has just been created, the dimensions of the imageButton change but the image doesn't appear. This is really frustrating and Any help resolving this is greatly appreciated.

MYCODE

```
@Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        switch (requestCode) {
        case REQUEST_CODE:  
            // If the file selection was successful
            if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {      
                if (data != null) {
                    // Get the URI of the selected file
                    final Uri uri = data.getData();

                    try {
                        // Create a file instance from the URI
                        final File file = FileUtils.getFile(uri);

                        Toast.makeText(Profile_Barber.this,"File Selected: "+file.getAbsolutePath(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        Log.e("URI", uri.toString());//Returns:  content://media/external/images/media/1834

                        Bitmap bmp = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(this.getContentResolver(), uri);

                        if(bmp==null){
                            Log.e("BMP NULL", "This that bullshit!");
                        }else{
                            Log.e("BMP NOT NULL", bmp.toString()); //Returns: BMP NOT NULL android.graphics.Bitmap@4152b5a0

                            profilepic.setImageBitmap(bmp);
                        }

 } catch (Exception e) {
                        Log.e("FileSelectorTestActivity", "File select error", e);
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            } 
            break;
        }
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    }
```

Comment: did you try to set the bitmap to a ImageView?

Comment: No, I haven't. Does it really make a difference whether it's a imageview or imageButton?

Comment: i mean, if you can make it in a ImageView, then we can make sure that the bitmap is cool, we can look for another reason.

Comment: Just tried with an ImageView and I'm getting the same behavior.

Comment: did you check the bmp instance, is it ok?

Comment: What do you mean by instance?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/33790/discussion-between-kevinhoo-and-dollabill)

Comment: you have already get path of image using final Uri uri = data.getData(); just  use img.setImageURI(yourimageuripath);

Comment: Based on the title to the question I really wanted to say - "because its broken."

Answer (score 1):

How about using this to decode image?

```
        Uri contentURI = Uri.parse(data.getDataString());        
        ContentResolver cr = getContentResolver();
        InputStream in = cr.openInputStream(contentURI);
        Bitmap pic = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(in,null,null);
```

Comment: or just using Uri imageUri = data.getData(); imageView.setImageUri(imageUri); to set a pictur

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion.  It's still giving me the same result though.  I'm using the aFileChooser library to access and select files from my SDCard.  Could that be the root of the issue?

Comment: i am not sure, how about just using myIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI); to pick file

Comment: Im at my wits end now. Not even the conventional way you just suggested is working.  SDcard must be corrupted or something.

Comment: sad.. are u trying all there with the usb wired connected? some devices will disabled sd card when wired connected.